# Write Spark dataframe to Hbase using phoenix connector

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hbase, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I have Hive table which points to Hbase table. I have a spark job which creates dataset having schema equal to hbase table. I am saving this dataframe to hbase table using below command.

```
sql.write().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("table", targetTable)
    .option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure)
    .insertInto(targetTable);
```

When executing I get below error..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.phoenix.hive.PhoenixStorageHandler.configureJobProperties(PhoenixStorageHandler.java:185)
at org.apache.phoenix.hive.PhoenixStorageHandler.configureOutputJobProperties(PhoenixStorageHandler.java:130)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveTableUtil$.configureJobPropertiesForStorageHandler(TableReader.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.SparkHiveWriterContainer.<init>(hiveWriterContainers.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.doExecute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:259)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
at com.lti.unitrax.data.load.IncrementalHiveTableLoadUnitraxMain.fullDataLoad(IncrementalHiveTableLoadUnitraxMain.java:166)
at com.lti.unitrax.data.load.TestDataLoad.main(TestDataLoad.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

I am using spark2 and HDP cluster.

Comment: There is a Spark HBase connector, you know, right?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: What's actually in your Dataframe? Are there any null values? Have you tried using the pagerank example here? https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html

Answer (score 1):

I know i am late in the game but saw this post. Thought my answer could help someone.

Here is how I have done in my implementation

1. df = Dataframe
2. zookeeperURL = zookeeper URL of your cluster
3. _tgtTable = Table in which you want to write data

```
df.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
  .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .options(collection.immutable.Map("zkUrl" -> zookeeperURL, "table" -> _tgtTable)) 
  .save()
```